# ReactJs double render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, rerender

When I try to refresh page it prints "1" twice.

But I'm not using any useState or variable update or state change I think.

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
//import { io } from "socket.io-client";
//const socket = io("ws://localhost:4000");

export default function App() {
  const newUser = () => {
    //socket.emit("newUser", { socketID: socket.id });
  };

  const checkUser = () => {
    //socket.emit("checkUser", { socketID: socket.id });
  };

  const resetUser = () => {
    //socket.emit("resetUser", { socketID: socket.id });
  };

  const checkSocket = () => {
    //console.log(socket);
  };

  const disconnectSocket = () => {
    //socket.emit("disconnect");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1");
  }, []);

  /*useEffect(() => {
    console.log("2", socket);
    //if(socket.id) socket.emit("newUser", {socketID: socket.id});
    //socket.on("checkUser", data => console.log("check", data));
    //socket.on("newUserResponse", data => console.log("newUserResponse", data));
    return () => {
    };
  }, [socket]);
  */

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={newUser}>New User</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={checkUser}>Check User</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={resetUser}>Reset User</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={checkSocket}>Check Socket</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={disconnectSocket}>Disconnect Socket</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you've got two render cause you've keep the Strict Mode

Comment: What exactly is StrictMode for?
What can be the advantages of using it in development?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is something introduced in React 18 where the component loads twice in strict mode. This only happens in development mode and NOT in production.

For more information see : https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

From the Docs :
[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly is StrictMode for?
What can be the advantages of using it in development?

Comment: You can give this a read to fully understand what Strct Mode in React is and how it helps developers : https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html . But TLDR, Strict Mode is a check that is added to your app using the strict mode tags, that checks for any wrong practices done by the dev and warn during development time. Strict Mode isn't run in production.

Comment: You can remove the strict mode check in your react app by removing this tag <React.StrictMode>, but I won't recommend it, as it helps devs write less buggy code.

Comment: How come in StrictMode a simple code prints the message twice?
This I want to understand.

Comment: What wrong practice, if any, has been done here?